# How can I write this file in Python, preferably using gzip, to a zipped file?

Tags: python, subprocess, gzip, gunzip

I have some code writing output to a file that I want zipped, but I can't figure out how I would write it to a zipped file.

```
subprocess.run([f"grep -i -m 1 'REMARK VINA RESULT:' ./output/{docking_type}/output_{filename} \
                            | awk '{{print $4}}' >> results_{rank}.txt; echo {filename} \
                            >> results_{rank}.txt"], shell=True)
```

At this point I can only see writing the output then taking that file and zipping it, but I'm hoping to combine those steps, since I am writing a very large number of files. From the gzip documentation this would be done via:

```
import gzip
content = b"Lots of content here"
with gzip.open('/home/joe/file.txt.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

Am I just misunderstanding gzip? Thanks for any help!

I've tried a few variations without success so far!

Comment: Do you want a .zip archive file? in that case you want the `zipfile` module. The `gzip` module just compresses a single file and is not an archive format, like the `gz` command line command.

Comment: Why are your running  a `subprocess` and using shell commands? It would seem straight forward to do what the `grep` and `awk` functionality is doing within Python. This would make your code more portable and easier to maintain. You would also have all the content in Python domain so using the `gzip` example would be straightforward. Do you have a small example of what is in the input file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import gzip
content = b"Lots of content here"
with gzip.open('/home/joe/file.txt.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content.encode()) # encoded
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write the output directly to a gzipped file.

Here's How you can achieve this.

```
import subprocess
import gzip

# run the shell command to get the result and filename
result = subprocess.run([f"grep -i -m 1 'REMARK VINA RESULT:' ./output/{docking_type}/output_{filename} \
                      | awk '{{print $4}}' && echo {filename}"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# convert the output to bytes
content = result.stdout

# write the content to a gzipped file
  with gzip.open(f'results_{rank}.txt.gz', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(content)
```

This will run the shell command and store the output in result.stdout, then write that output directly to a gzipped file with .gz extension.